# Android ListView reordering based on startAt / endAt

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase query;

```
Query fixtureQuery = ref.orderByChild("played").startAt(0).endAt(1);
```

This is used to populate a ListView in an Android app. The range of numbers for played are as follows;

- 0 - Not played
- 1 - Game in progress
- 2 - Game finished

What I have noticed is that when a game is in progress, 1, that the ListView redraws (which I want to keep everything realtime) but it always puts the games with a 1 value at the bottom of the ListView (so it doesn't keep its original placing in the list).

It appears that the numbers after startAt(x) will always appear ordered sequentially irrelevant of their place in the database.

Does anyone know how to stop this happening? Or do I need to order by a field so it ignores the startAt / endAt ordering that is being applied?

Answer (score 2):

Items have no fixed place in the database. They're JSON objects, which are inherently unordered. Order is only given to items when you query for them, or when they're shown in a UI. For example, the Firebase Database console shows items in order of their key.

In you case, you're asking for:

```
ref.orderByChild("played").startAt(0).endAt(1)
```

Which means the items are ordered by the numeric order of their `played` property, where `0` comes before `1`.

If you want to get the items in a specific order of status, you should ensure that the numeric values you use to indicate each status reflect the order in which you want to retrieve them. If you have various sort orders, it is not uncommon to add properties for each and assign those values accordingly.

Alternatively, you can simply first load the data and then re-order it client-side.

Comment: Thanks, I suspect this was the case, but as previous posts have mentioned its ordered as it is record 1, record 2, etc... I just assumed that would be maintained irrelevant of startAt queries. I have a date field I'm going to order on, so that should resolve my issue.